# Чтение тегов MP3 без использования сторонних библиотек (Python)

Tags: python, mp3

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой, мне нужно получить теги из mp3 файла без использования сторонних библиотек на Python, перевернул документацию с работой мультимедиа, ничего не мог толкового найти. Что делать?

Comment: Гуглится на `Python mp3 tag`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948 / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013576

Comment: Да, этот материал я находил, но там библиотека eyed3 Используется

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить тэги mp3 файла без библиотеки придется читать по байтам файл, и находить теги самостоятельно. Вот простой пример, чтобы понять какая версия ID3 используется:

```
f = open("filename.mp3", "rb")
version = f.read(3)
print(version)
```

Для моего файла вывод такой: `b'ID3'`, в других случаях может быть `TAG` или `TAG+` (Для случая с расширеным тэгом ID3, нужно читать 4 байта).

Структура [ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) - простая, ее можно легко разобрать.

Структура `ID3v2` - довольно таки сложная, поэтому лучше использовать стороннюю библиотеку.

Comment: "TAG+" никак не может быть, потому что вы считали только 3 символа)

Comment: Да конечно) Надо заглянуть в 4 байт и посмотреть есть ли там плюс.